# Erlang compiliation with maven on windows

Tags: windows, maven, path, erlang

I try to compile some erlang with maven. 
I use the maven-erlang-plugin to do this task.

It works fine on linux but when I try to compile on a windows this error occurs:

```
    [erlang:validate]

    [erlang:initialize]

    [erlang:extract-dependencies]

    [erlang:reload-dependencies]

    [erlang:generate-resources]

    [erlang:compile]

    C O M P I L E R

    No MIBs to compile.
    Errors:

    c:UsersDelkaspoDocumentsNetBeansProjectsirtualbrownpaperMiddleWare rcmainrlang oto.erl:none
 I/O error
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 BUILD FAILURE
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total time: 2.438s Finished at: Tue Jun 05 11:52:46 CEST 2012 Final Memory: 11M/108M
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Failed to execute goal eu.lindenbaum:maven-erlang-plugin:2.2.0:compile (default-compile) on project middleware: Failed to >compile [C:UsersDelkaspoDocumentsNetBeansProjectsirtualbrownpaperMiddleWare rcmainrlang oto.erl]. -> [Help 1]
    To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

    For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
    Successfully shut down 'middleware-maven-erlang-plugin-backend@ipadrress'
```

It looks like he interprets the backslash of windows.

for information :
maven-erlang-plugin -> 2.3.0 (I tried the others version -> same issue)
maven -> 2.2.1

Any ideas ?

Thanks for all.

Comment: Could I ask you, why do you use maven instead of rebar common practice(or sinan)?

Comment: Because I use continuous integration with Jenkins and the project have 3 different part : one in java for GUI (with jinterface), the other is in erlang and the third is the server.
And i'm more familiar with maven (it's my first erlang project) :) !